# How to update bottomnavigation when press back?

Tags: java, android

I have BottomNavigationView and I want to update it when I press back button.
How should I do, update work only start new Activity.

Here code

```
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation_id);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.firstpage_id);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

//        select item from bottom navigation
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.firstpage_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        newActivity(MainActivity.class);
                        break;

                    case R.id.offergape_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "offer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        newActivity(OfferActivity.class);
                        break;

                    case R.id.requestpage_id:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "need", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        newActivity(RequestActivity.class);
                        break;

                    case R.id.searchpage_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        newActivity(SearchActivity.class);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

In other activity update bottomNavigationView I change only

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(3);
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  //do your method call here 
}
```

this will used to make changes when back is pressed override this function in your required activity